# Sum matrixes as numbers not strings ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, matrix

I am trying to sum 2 matrixes from a CSV file
Currently, I put them into to arrays and then transform the array into matrixes. However, when I print them, I get concatenated strings not summed integers.

```
require 'csv'
require 'matrix'

matrix1 = "./matrix1.csv"
matrix2 = "./matrix2.csv"

line_count = 0
elements_in_line_count = 0
arr1 = Array.new    #=> []
arr2 = Array.new    #=> []

CSV.foreach(matrix1) do |row|
  arr1 << row
  line_count += 1
  elements_in_line_count =  row.size
end

n1 = elements_in_line_count
m1 = line_count 

# find n and m of second matrix 

line_count = 0
elements_in_line_count = 0

CSV.foreach(matrix2) do |row|
 # print row
   arr2 << row
  line_count += 1
  elements_in_line_count =  row.size
end

puts Matrix.rows(arr1) + Matrix.rows(arr2)
```

For example, CSV 1 is:

```
  1,2
  3,4
```

Same for CSV 2.
The output is

```
Matrix[[11, 22], [33, 44]]
```

But I want it to be [2,4],[6,8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reading in the CSV, all columns will be strings, so you'll have to manually do the conversion to a number in the code.

If all of the columns of the CSV are intended to be numbers, you can add `.map(&:to_i)` to the row line. Like this:

```
CSV.foreach(matrix1) do |row|
  arr1 << row.map(&:to_i) # <-- this will turn everything in the row into a number
  line_count += 1
  elements_in_line_count =  row.size
end
```

Answer (score 3):

When you read in the CSV, by default it reads in all the rows/columns as strings, the Ruby [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#Converters) class can take an optional parameter to `foreach` and `new` and similar methods called `:converters` that it will use to convert each applicable column. One of the converters it can take is

> :integer
>
> Converts any field Integer() accepts.

So you can also change your code to look like:

```
csv_options = { converters: [:integer] }
CSV.foreach(matrix1, csv_options) do |row|
# ...
CSV.foreach(matrix2, csv_options) do |row|
```

to achieve results similar to calling `map(&:to_i)` on each row.

Answer (score 2):

```
[m1, m2].map do |m|
  CSV.foreach(m).map { |row| row.map(&:to_i) }
end.reduce do |m1, m2|
  m1.map.with_index do |row, idx|
    row.zip(m2[idx]).map { |cell1, cell2| cell1 + cell2 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not `map { |cells| cells.reduce(:+) }`? :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland because of zip before, there are always two elements, here reduce is an overkill.

Comment: I couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to add matrices, consider using Ruby's built-in [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class, and the instance method [Matrix#+](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-2B) in particular.

Let's first construct three CSV files.

```
fname1 = 't1.csv'
fname2 = 't2.csv'
fname3 = 't3.csv'

File.write(fname1, "1,2\n3,4")
  #=> 7
File.write(fname2, "100,200\n300,400")
  #=> 15
File.write(fname3, "1000,2000\n3000,4000")
  #=> 19
```

We can sum the underlying matrices as follows.

```
require 'csv'
require 'matrix'

fnames = [fname1, fname2, fname3]

fnames.drop(1).reduce(matrix_from_CSV(fnames.first)) do |t,fname|
  t + matrix_from_CSV(fname)
end.to_a
  #=> [[1101, 2202],
  #    [3303, 4404]]

def matrix_from_CSV(fname)
  Matrix[*CSV.read(fname, converters: [:integer])]
end
```

I borrowed `converters: [:integer]` from @Simple's answer. I wasn't aware of that.